# Finding a particular section of a string

Tags: java, regex

I have a string and i am looking to get a particular section of it to save.

Assets/Topics/Update/filename_hj10134532.html.xls

I want to get the "hj10134532" section. How would i go about extracting that part of the string?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You give us an example, but not a rule what constitutes the pattern. The characters used? hj[0-9]*? Something between _ and .? Only before .html? .html.xls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String s="Assets/Topics/Update/filename_hj10134532.html.xls";
System.out.println(s.split("\\.")[0].split("_")[1]);
//out hj10134532
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do:

```
String input = "Assets/Topics/Update/filename_hj10134532.html.xls";
String part = input.substring(input.lastIndexOf("_") + 1, input.indexOf("."));
```

Comment: @Pshemo: Oops! miss-understood your comment. Fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If following is the fixed format

```
sometext_requiredText.html.xls
```

then you could do it by following way

1. Split the string by `_`
2. Take the second portion (i.e. `str.split("_")[1]` check length of resultant array)
3. Find the first occurrence of `.` using `indexOf()`
4. Use `substring(int, int)`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there's a much simpler way than what you three have posted.

```
    String s="Assets/Topics/Update/filename_hj10134532.html.xls";
    return s.substring(s.indexOf("_"),s.indexOf("."));
```

Much more readable, and no string splitting required.

Answer (score -1):

Check:

```
String pat = "hj10134532";
if ("Assets/Topics/Update/filename_hj10134532.html.xls".contains (pat))
    return pat;
```

if it contains ("hj10134532"), return it. There is no need to extract it.